# Is there a Fibonacci identity?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $F(n)$ be the n-th Fibonacci number. Is there any identity to simplify the following summation.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}F(i)^2F(n-i)^2 $$

Comment: With the help of a CAS it is not difficult to prove that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} F_n^2 e^{nix} = \frac{i\tan\frac{x}{2}}{3-2\cos x}=\frac{i\sin x}{(1+\cos x)(3-2\cos x)} $$

Comment: Start from the [Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html), one can simplify the sum and get $$\sum_{k=1}^n (F_k F_{n-k})^2 = \frac{1}{25}\big[(n-1)L_{2n}+2 F_{2n+1} + 4n(-1)^n\big]$$
where $F_n, L_n$ are  Fibonacci and Lucas numbers respectively.

Answer (score 3):

The first few terms are $1,2,9,26,84$.  Putting this into OEIS gives [A136429](http://oeis.org/A136429).  There you can find a generating function, an expression as a self-convolution, and the first 100 terms.  Also, they satisfy the recurrence

$$a_{n+6}=4a_{n+5}-10a_{n+3}+4a_{n+1}-a_n$$

In principle, you can find a closed form from this, but that would require finding all the roots to a sixth-degree polynomial.  Luckily, that polynomial isn't too difficult, and has roots $$-1, \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
Hence the general sequence satisfying the above recurrence is $$a_n=A(-1)^n+B(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+Cn(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+D(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+En(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n$$
You can substitute the known five initial values, above, for $a_2$ through $a_6$, which will lead to a system of five linear equations in the five unknowns $A,B,C,D,E$.  Then you may solve this system to get a closed form for $a_n$.   See Robert Israel's worked out closed form in the comments.

Comment: Closed form $$a_k = {\frac { \left(  \left( -15\,k-37 \right) \sqrt {5}+35\,k+85 \right) 
 \left( 3/2-\sqrt {5}/2 \right) ^{k}}{250}}+{\frac { \left( 
 \left( 15\,k+37 \right) \sqrt {5}+35\,k+85 \right)  \left( 
\sqrt {5}/2+3/2 \right) ^{k}}{250}}+{\frac {4\, \left( -1 \right) ^{k}
 \left( k+2 \right) }{25}}
$$
(where your expression is $a_{n-2}$).

Comment: Since $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} = \left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2$, there should be a reasonably simple closed form expression using the Fibonacii/Lucas numbers $F_{2n}$ and $L_{2n}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$F(i)=\frac{a^i-b^i}{a-b},\ a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\ b=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\\ F^2(i)=\frac{a^{2i}+b^{2i}-2(-1)^i}{5}\implies S(x)=\sum_{i\ge 1}F^{2i}x^i=\frac{\sum_{i\ge 1}a^{2i}x^i+\sum_{i\ge 1}b^{2i}x^i-2\sum_{i\ge 1}(-x)^i}{5}=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{1-a^2x}+\frac{1}{1-b^2x}-\frac{2}{1+x}\right)=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{x^2+5x}{1-2x-2x^2+x^3}\right)$$ Then the given expression will be the coefficient of $x^{n}$ in the expansion of $S^2(x)$